# Compute means across a list on R

Tags: r, list, mean

I have a list with the following structure:

```
> str(test)
List of 5
$ :List of 2
..$ : num [1:4] 0.0544 0.0839 0.0486 0.043
..$ : num [1:4] 0.0799 0.2434 0.0373 0.2166
$ :List of 2
..$ : num [1:6] 0.938 1.047 1.022 0.689 0.39 ...
..$ : num [1:6] 0.871 0.25 0.824 0.664 0.481 ...
$ :List of 2
..$ : num [1:4] 0.000598 0.000923 0.000535 0.000473
..$ : num [1:4] 0.001039 0.003164 0.000485 0.002816
$ :List of 2
..$ : num [1:6] 0.01032 0.01152 0.01124 0.00758 0.00429 ...
..$ : num [1:6] 0.01133 0.00325 0.01071 0.00864 0.00625 ...
$ :List of 2
..$ : num -0.659
..$ : num -0.962
```

I want to compute the mean of each entry, i.e. for the first entry I want:

```
x <- mean(c(0.0544, 0.0839, 0.0486, 0.043))
y <- mean(c(0.0799, 0.2434, 0.0373, 0.2166))
```

And finally the mean of those two results = mean(c(x,y).

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Check out `lapply`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the \*apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: `lapply(test, function(l) sapply(l, mean, na.rm = TRUE))`. Then `lapply(result, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: `rapply` might be the most applicable for the first problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample data - one (parent) list of (child) lists.

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- list(
            list(runif(4),runif(4)),
            list(runif(6),runif(6))
           )
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.62911404 0.06178627 0.20597457 0.17655675 0.68702285 0.38410372
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.7698414 0.4976992 0.7176185 0.9919061 0.3800352 0.7774452
```

Get the means of each child list:

```
foo_means <- lapply(foo, lapply, mean)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.5296734
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.6763862
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.3574264
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.6890909
```

To get the average of (child) averages for each (parent) list element:

```
lapply(foo_means, function(x) mean(unlist(x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0.6030298
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.5232587
```

Answer (score 3):

The first question appears to be a perfect use for `rapply`. Using the same sample data as provided above in @ngm's answer, you can do:

```
foo2 <- rapply(foo, mean, how = "replace")

foo2
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 0.5296734
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 0.6763862
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 0.3574264
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 0.6890909
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered many times.
 It is as simple as

```
mean(unlist(lapply(mylist,sapply,mean)))
```

Follow this link.

[Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: Yeah, I knew that lapply would be the correct way to do it, but I was having some trouble with the lists inside a list issue... However, I found that lapply(test, FUN = function(x) {mean(unlist(x))}) also seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Since the elements of your list are also lists, then use some nested `lapply`'s to get the means of each list.

```
lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x, mean))
```

If you like a matrix as an output, you can do

```
sapply(test, function(x) sapply(x, mean))
```

With the `sapply`, you can get the means of each pair with

```
colMeans(sapply(test, function(x) sapply(x, mean, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `modify_depth` function from the `purrr` package. Take example posted by @ngm

```r
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)
foo <- list(list(runif(4), runif(4)),
            list(runif(6), runif(6)))

modify_depth(foo, 2, mean)

#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.5296734
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.6763862
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 0.3574264
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 0.6890909
```

**Edit**: to calculate the mean of all elements in the 1st level of that list

```r
modify_depth(foo, 2, mean) %>% 
  map(flatten_dbl) %>% 
  map_dbl(mean)

modify_depth(foo, 2, mean) %>% 
  simplify_all() %>% 
  map_dbl(mean)

[1] 0.60303 0.52326
```

Created on 2018-04-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).